# All Programs is missing program shortcuts in Windows 7 RC 7100

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I've tried to find a fix for this using the 'so disorganized and overly loud' phpBB hell forums and to no avail.

On my Windows 7 Build 7100 when I click Start > All Programs I don't see any of my programs and I've tried a few fixes and they just don't seem to work.

When I right click All Programs and select Open I can see a Programs folder and few icons. Any help in restoring them will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a known bug in build 7100, and it appears to co-relate with the total number of shortcuts present in your Start Menu.

To solve this, trying copying shortcuts from the User start menu to the All Users start menu, and also try deleting unnecessary shortcuts.

As an aside, see if you can upgrade to the Enterprise 90-day trial.

**EDIT : Found the original thread I referred to when I was hit by this bug a few months back.**

For an in-depth forum discussion on this, I refer you to this thread on [Windows 7 Forum](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/4354-program-icons-missing-all-programs-menu.html)s.

P.S Hope SuperUser was more helpful than those 'so disorganized and overly loud' phpBB hell forums, from which this answer originated from too. ;) Give and take, we are just more... disciplined here that's all.

Comment: Thank you! This is the RC and I did see that forum entry earlier, played a bit with it and gave up hope. I will try it once more and see if reducing the number of shortcuts and folders I have helps. As we close in on October 22nd I'm sure this issue will not appear since we've got to install everything back!!! Aaah!!

Comment: the magic of Oct 22nd is kinda lost - since i'm playing with Enterprise 90-day now (will get a key via my company soon hurhurhur). -laughs- hang in there ymasood, it's only slightly more than a month away. Windows 7 FTW!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before see here [All start menu items have disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/21519/all-start-menu-items-have-disappeared)

Also see here [with more details on the know bug](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/08/all-programs-in-start-menu-not-shown-in-windows-7/)

Answer (score 1):

After spending long time this simple solution worked for me:

- Go to START menu
- Right Click on All Program
- Choose OPEN ALL USERS
- In the opened folder Unhide all files and
  folders specially PROGRAM folder and
  its subfolders
- Apply and OK

Done!