# Windows 7, start menu icons are gone

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All start menu items have disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/21519/all-start-menu-items-have-disappeared)

Somehow, i don't know why, start menu lost most of it's programs stored at "all programs". is there an easy way to restore them?
After looking here

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

and here

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

i realized that shortcut files aren't deleted, but it seems that start menu needs to "refresh" itself...
How to solve my problem?

Comment: Try typing: regsvr32 /i shell32.dll in the run box. http://www.5starsupport.com/xp-faq/1-121.htm

Comment: I've seen this before after some malware was installed.  Update your anti-virus and do a full system scan.  You might have to repair the Windows install afterwards and/or re-install the applications that have missing shortcuts.

Comment: Probably you have used some thrid party program to substitute or customize the Startmenu, such as Start Menu 7 o ClassicShell or you hacked some registry such as HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders.
Have a look here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21992/show-the-classic-all-programs-menu-in-the-start-menu-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't any (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system. A free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its clean might be a good idea.

**Here is the important part;** Once you know the system is clean, open an elevated command prompt and run `SFC /SCANNOW` to run the System File Check. When it is done, reboot and see if things are back to normal.